# Magento Data Profiles not showing file after upload

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Im getting an error when using the data profiles in magento 1.9 I selected a file to upload clicked save and continue edit then when I goto run the profile the select file drop down box doesn't have the file I just uploaded, any reason why this could be happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the var/import folder the file which you have uploaded is there or not, if it is not there change the folder permission 777 and re upload the files. Changing on the permission of the var/import folder may help.

Hope it helps.

Thanks